# How do I pass a string to a factory

Tags: angularjs

How do I pass `query` to my factory?

Controller ..

```
myApp.controller('IonAutocompleteController', function($scope, items)
{
$scope.getTestItems = function(query)
{
    items.list(function(items) {
    return items;
  });
});
```

Factory..

```
myApp.factory('items', function($http){
    return {
      list: function(callback){
        $http.get('http://192.168.100.100/foosync/products/' + query).success(callback);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Is the query defined in a global scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your variable names are a mess. Items and items will confuse you in the long run. About your problem, just add another parameter.

Factory:

```
myApp.factory('itemsFactory', function($http){
    return {
      list: function(query, callback){
        $http.get('http://192.168.100.100/foosync/products/' + query).success(callback);
      }
    };
  });
```

Now your controller:

```
myApp.controller('IonAutocompleteController', function($scope, itemsFactory)
{
  $scope.getTestItems = function(query) {
    itemsFactory.list(query, function(items) {
      return items;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as you would any other parameter to a function:

```
$scope.getTestItems = function(query) {
    items.list(query, function(items) {
      return items;
    });
}
```

Mod your list function to take an extra parameter:

```
myApp.factory('items', function($http){
    return {
      list: function(query, callback) {
        $http.get('http://192.168.100.100/foosync/products/' + query).success(callback);
      }
    };
  });
```